# postgresql pg_dump without schema name

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore, postgresql-10

pg_dump version 10.3 started adding the schema name explicitly to the table name. So what used to be

```
INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES (1);
```

Is now

```
INSERT INTO public.table (id) VALUES (1);
```

How can you switch it off? My problem is, that I dump this into a mariadb where you don't have schema names.

Answer (score 2):

I also searched for a way to switch the schema name, but it turns out there is none. The reason is this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/A_Guide_to_CVE-2018-1058:_Protect_Your_Search_Path

In my work I now use new variant of dump with renaming schemas in transaction.

Comment: Which new variant? That would help answer the question.

Comment: Variant that created by pg_dump new vertion - with schema names in queries. Answer the question is "It can't be switch off in patched vertions of pg_dump". Use old vestions or rename schema to "big_special_name_for_replace" before dumping and replace this name in dump file.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just the INSERT statements that you care about, like me, then I believe this is safe, and will remove the "public" schema from your tables.

```
sed -i -e 's/^INSERT INTO public\./INSERT INTO /' <filename.sql>
```

It modifies the file in place, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

With a few [modifications](https://github.com/tindzk/postgres/commit/be7b60cb7dfd3806319fab0c4ec3345403541b5c) to the `pg_dump` sources, you can restore the previous behaviour such that `INSERT` statements do not include the schema name.

To build a Docker image with these changes, create a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/postgresql

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    alpine-sdk \
    perl \
    readline-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    bison \
    flex \
    git \
    coreutils \
    linux-headers \
    util-linux-dev

RUN git clone \
    --depth 1 \
    --branch feat/schema-less-pg-dump-11 \
    https://github.com/tindzk/postgres.git .

RUN ./configure && make

RUN cp src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump /usr/bin/ && \
    cp ./src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.so* /usr/lib/

RUN apk del alpine-sdk \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /usr/src/postgresql

CMD ["pg_dump"]
```

Afterwards, use it as follows:

```bash
docker build -t pgdump-11 .

docker run \
  -e PGPASSWORD=$db_password \
  -v "$(pwd)":/data/ \
  pgdump-11 \
  pg_dump \
  --verbose \
  "postgres://$db_user@$db_host:$db_port/$db_name" \
  --schema $db_schema \
  --file /data/dump.sql
```

This approach is more robust than pattern matching and avoids the risk of false positives.

Answer (score -3):

Of course it's just linux decision (not postgres), but it helps you i suppose

```
sed -i 's/public.//g' your_dmp_file
```

P.s. I didn't check this, may be you should fix it

Comment: This wouldn't work, any table with values that happen to contain "public." would be incorrectly removed.

Comment: Thank you. That's actually what I have done, because I'm sure there is no data containing the string 'public.' However it's kind of ugly. I'm surprised there is no proper way to switch this off.

Answer (score -3):

If you have Docker installed you can do a trick:

```sh
docker run -it postgres:10.2 pg_dump postgresql://user:pass@host/database
```

Comment: doesnt wotrk with newer dbs `pg_dump: server version: 12.2; pg_dump version: 10.2 (Debian 10.2-1.pgdg90+1)
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch`

Answer (score -4):

Execute this command in your postgresql console (connected to your database):

```
set search_path to public;
```

Comment: There are no search paths in MySQL.

Comment: @pensnarik the question was PostgreSQL specific...